# Python. Вопрос насчет метода list и reverse

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
string = "1,2,3,4,5" 
print(type(string)) # тип строка
newlist = list(string).reverse() # в этой строке что то не то? Он ведь преобразует строку в список и переворачивает разве нет?
print(type(newlist)) # NoneType. Это как? метод list возвращает же список.
print(newlist) # И еще вопрос. Почему он не переворачивает строку ? Результат none.
```

Answer (score 5):

`list(string).reverse()` переворачивает список на месте (не возвращая результат):

```
>>> a = [1, 2, 3]
>>> a.reverse()
>>> print(a)
>>> [3, 2, 1]
```

Чтобы получить копию списка в обратном порядке, можно использовать `reversed`:

```
>>> a = [1, 2, 3]
>>> print(reversed(a))
>>> [3, 2 1]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
string = "1,2,3,4,5" 
rev_string = ''.join(reversed(string))
```

А может вы хотите так:

```
string = "1,2,3,4,5" 
rev_string = ','.join(reversed(string.split(',')))
```

Comment: Оуу, спасибо, а метод reverse не существует что ли? Это два разных метода? reverse and reversed? Почему интерпретатор не ругается. На сайте точно такое действие сделали с reverse и все заработало.

Comment: @Success Да не. Тут есть тонкость. Билт-ин, что я заюзал _возвращает_ перевернутый лист. А ваш метод _переворачивает_ лист и ничего не _возвращает_ (т.е. None) ;)

Comment: 2 разных метода, 1 возвращает повёрнутое а 2й поворачивает и возвращает нон.

Comment: @Интик Знаешь я тоже часто читаю нон, но он н**A**н

Comment: это от лени ) читать как видишь, а не вспоминать все правила

Comment: @Интик ok.......

Comment: @Success Ну, это ж как `sort` и `sorted`, такие вещи надо просто знать )